# Python Mock Not Getting Attributes

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking

The functionality I am trying to test is as follows. I am trying to mock the `client` in this function, which comes from my `auth` module. I am trying to make the client's `get` function return a Mock object, which contains a property `text` which refers to our `mock_response` (seen further down).

```
def get_person_by_email(email):
    client = auth.client()
    # print(client) = <Mock name='mock_client()' id='4324810640'>
    response = client.get(url="http://..." + email)
    # print(response) = <Mock name='mock_client().get()' id='4575780304'>
    # print(response.text) = <Mock name='mock_client().get().text' id='4348534608'>
    return jsonify(loads(utils.strip_security_string(response.text)))
```

The function which is throwing `TypeError: 'Mock' object has no attribute '__getitem__'` is:

```
def strip_security_string(json_string):
    return "\n".join(json_string.split("\n")[1:])
```

Which simply removes the first line from the response.

And finally, the code which is trying to test the above functionality:

```
def test_get_person_by_email():
    with app.test_client() as client:
        with app.app_context():
            mock_response = """security-string
                {"key":"value"}"""
            mock_client = Mock(name='mock_client')
            mock_client.get.return_value = Mock(text=mock_response)
            with patch.object(auth, 'client', mock_client):
                response = client.get("http://.../email/email@domain.com")
```

Comment: I don't see how or where the bottom block of code is testing the `strip_security_string` function. Can you please show exactly where this function is getting called, which is where you say the exception is being thrown?

Comment: You probably need to use a `MagicMock` object, not a `Mock` object, although I would expect an error message like "'Mock' object does not support indexing".

Comment: @mattm Hi Mattm, that is not the function I am trying to test. The function I am trying to test invokes that function, and that is where the error is arising. That function is invoked at the end of the `get_person_by_email` function.

Comment: @chepner Hi Chepner. I've tried changing it with a MagicMock, and though I do not get a TypeError, I get a JSON error as there is no object to decode. This is because `response.text` is showing the Mock object, instead of the text.

Comment: What are you trying to mock, if not `client`? The purpose of the mock is to provide plausible output from `client.get` without actually having to connect to the remote URL. It's your responsibility to make sure the mock is configured to provide an object that has a suitable `text` attribute.

Comment: @Chepner The mock attribute I created (am trying to create) has a GET function which returns a Mock, which contains a `text` attribute. I am indeed trying to mock the client, it's just not working as I posted above. It seems to work if I assign these attributes from the `type()` of the mock as a `PropertyMock` but this doesn't seem right to me.

Comment: Yes: you are configuring `client.get` to return a `Mock`, but that `Mock`'s `text` attribute is itself a `Mock`, not something that your JSON parser can do anything with.

Comment: @Chepner That's the problem, I need the text attribute to return the String, not another Mock. How do I do that?

Comment: @cristian text attribute return a Mock object just because you never hook the text property to the right object. You had hocked it to `client.get()..text ` instead of `client().get().text`. If you don't want to call the Mock object you can just set the return_value of mock_client when you create it, but it's the same thing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not an mock expert but you could try to change `mock_client().get.return_value` with `mock_client.get.return_value`.  That's because the code use `auth.client()` instead of `auth.client`

If you don't want to access to the `mock_client()` in the Mock creation stage you can do

```
mock_client_obj = Mock(name='mock_client_obj')
mock_client_obj.get.return_value = Mock(text=mock_response)
mock_client = Mock(name='mock_client',return_value=mock_client_obj)
```

Or a more simple

```
mock_client = Mock(name='mock_client')
mock_client.return_value.get.return_value.text = mock_response
```

Comment: Hi Michele, would that not invoke the mock_client object though?

Comment: @Cristian `mock_client()` give just the `Mock`'s `return_value`: in your case the default value that means a new `Mock()` object. On that object you can add a `get` method with its `return_value`. In your question you wrote that `# print(response.text) = <Mock name='mock_client().get().text' id='4348534608'>` that shows that `mock_client().get().text` was called instead of `mock_client.get().text`

Comment: Running `mock_client()`, though it does correctly set the attributes as I'd like, makes a call to the Mock; this is not desired.

Comment: @cristian why call mack_client() is not desiderated? It is exactly what the function that you would like to test do.

Comment: But I want the function I am trying to test to call the mock. In your example I am calling the Mock while setting it up which sets the mock's `called` attribute to True before it's even been used.

Comment: @cristian I've changed my answer. Take a look if it ok now.

Comment: Using the `return_value` on the get, and setting the text in the constructor seems to work perfectly. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

On closer look, `mock_response` is not set to a valid JSON value. Perhaps you mean something like

```
mock_reponse= """[ "security-string", { "key": "value" } ]"""
```

See http://json.org for the grammar that describes correct values.

Comment: @cheper Some REST clients return a security string (some JS security issue). The code takes care of this by stripping the security string. The JSON is correctly parsed and is not the problem.